# Does anyone know why Ubuntu can't shut down even though I ask it to?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have done some research and it seems that this is a common problem and I just installed the latest Ubuntu today on my computer. However, for some reason when I click the shut down button it always restarts instead of shutting down. I have already tried all those terminal commands to shut it down, but those don't work either. It always restarts itself.. Is there anyway I can power it off without having to resort to manually holding my computer's power button?

Edit:

I tried those grub update things too, but the commands I get from the forums don't seem to work anyways so that's also one solution that wouldn't work.

Comment: Belongs on askubuntu.com; possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/515225/ubuntu-server-restarting-instead-of-shutting-down

Comment: I am happy that you direct me to another similar post, but it's 1 month old and not even solved..Was it really necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. Your question is off-topic here, and we close off-topic questions because they are clutter and noise on this site. Directing you to the other post is the proper thing to do, as you now know that a) there is a more appropriate site for this type of question, and b) that the question has already been asked and no one seems to know the answer, meaning there is no point in your posting it again.

Answer (score 0):

try this one on the terminal:

```
sudo init 0
```

Comment: Tried it, all it does it keep restarting >.<" Very disappointed right now after coming from Windows 7